# Sonicwall SSLVPN Default Gateway Not Being Set

Tags: vpn, firewall, sonicwall

I am setting up a SonicWall SSLVPN on SonicOS 6.5 and am having issues with the default gateway being handed out to the client. When setting up the VPN I created an SSLVPN network (10.10.0.0/24). I am able to connect to the VPN and am handed an IP within the SSLVPN Network range. I am however unable to connect to anything on the X0 Network (10.0.0.0/24). In the SSLVPN > Client Settings I gave access to the X0 Subnet Client Route.

[Client Routes Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7gXz.png)

[Address Objects Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRxV9.png)

[NetExtender | CLI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjMyx.png)

For some reason the Subnet the I keep getting from the VPN interface is a /32 instead of the /24 that I set in the Address Object. From the SonicWall Documentation guides it doesn't look like I missed anything when setting this up; however, it still isn't working. Any help would be appreciated